# How to call a command line program in WiX

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I want to call a command line program of OpenOffice in WiX. To do so, I created a custom action, as seen below:

```
<CustomAction Id="ca_RunOpenOfficeProgram" Return="check" Directory="TARGETDIR"  ExeCommand="cmd.exe /K &quot;C:\OpenOffice.org3\program\unopgk.com list --shared&quot;" />
```

The Custom Action is being run in an Install Execute Sequence:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>            
  <Custom Action="ca_RunOpenOfficeProgram" Before="InstallFinalize" />
 </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

When running the resulting MSI-File, I receive the following error message in a command line:

```
Invalid command 'C:\OpenOffice.org3\program\unopkg.com' could not be found.
```

Well, of course, the command is available and I may run it from command line. But it just doesnt work if the command line is being called by WiX.
It`s also notable that the part 'list --shared' is completely ignored.

Does anyone know what`s going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for my problem:

1) As written in my answer to Toms post, I had in typo in the command line ... stupid.
2) The quotes regarding the command line call had been misplaced (Toms answer)
3) I found out that running 'unopkg.com' with the 'shared' parameter is only executed when the command line is being run with administration rights. I thought that the attribute 'impersonated="yes"' in my CustomAction would be enough, but it didn`t help. 
Guess I have to dig deeper into documentation of WiX regarding UAC.

Also thanks to Ralf. I didnt try his solutions, but you might give it a shot.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using the [`ShellExecute` custom action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/run_program_after_install.htm) from the WiX toolset.

Here is the sample code:

```
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#myapplication.exe]" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />
```

Change the `Value` of property `WixShellExecTarget` to `cmd.exe /K &quot;C:\OpenOffice.org3\program\unopgk.com list --shared&quot;` and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that `cmd.exe /K "C:\OpenOffice.org3\program\unopgk.com list --shared"` works? It looks like you have the quotes in the wrong place.

And, do you really want the console window kept open (`/k`)? Does the user have to enter more commands before the installation continues? You might want `/c` instead. See the help with `cmd /?`.

But, if there is only one command needed, why not just run the program directly?

```
ExeCommand="&quot;C:\OpenOffice.org3\program\unopgk.com&quot; list --shared"
```

Finally, if the above is the only command needed and assuming `C:\OpenOffice.org3\program\unopgk.com` is a console application, a useless console window will be opened. This can be avoided with WiX's [QtExecCmdLine](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm) custom action.

---

If you are running the program to gather information, and it is a console application, you could do:

```
cmd /c &quot;C:\OpenOffice.org3\program\unopgk.com&quot; list --shared >path\out.txt
```

and use another custom action to read the file and make decisions on it or show it to the user in a Windows Installer dialog. This would be a better experience than leaving the user with a console window with a blinking prompt that they have to exit out of.

Comment: Had I typo, the program is called 'unopkg.com'.

Corrected it, my CustomAction looks like this now:

`<CustomAction Id="ca_RunOpenOfficeProgram" Return="check" Directory="TARGETDIR" Execute="deferred" ExeCommand="&quot;C:\OpenOffice.org3\program\unopkg.com&quot; list --shared" Impersonate="yes" />`

When running the MSI, I receive the following error message:
'There is ap roblem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personal [...]'

Comment: Check the log file. The return value (exit code) of the program might be important. To run msiexec with logging see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370536(v=vs.85).aspx).